# Aircraft lifetime and maintenance

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Since it cannot be expected that the materials used for aircraft contruction have infinite lifetime and sooner or later they will deteriorate, how does aircraft maintenance work?

Are there schedules based on which certain components have to be checked or substituted in order to prolong the aircraft lifetime? Will the aircraft be unusable anyway after a certain amount of flight hours?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, see [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/68/who-decides-an-aircrafts-maintenance-schedule), [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3370/why-are-older-airplanes-still-in-use), and [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11659/is-there-any-limit-by-faa-on-the-age-of-aircraft-to-be-operational).

Comment: heavily edited in order to improve readibility (I should have maintained the OP intentions)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the most-similar question ([Is there any limit on the age of an aircraft?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11659/is-there-any-limit-by-faa-on-the-age-of-aircraft-to-be-operational)) - If you don't think that one answers your question leave a comment and I can reopen this question